# Google Places API Request fails without user-agent header

Tags: python, python-requests, google-places-api

We have a python application that uses the requests library to talk to google places quite a bit. Traditionally, that looked something like this:

```
import requests
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json"
payload = {
    "sensor": "false",
     "key": YOUR_KEY_HERE,
     "placeid": SOME_PLACE_ID_HERE,
}
response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
content = response.text
```

However, today we abruptly started getting 403 errors saying our traffic was unusual which brought down the entire app. After much trial and error and hair pulling out, I tried using the good ole urllib2 library and it worked, as did the exact same request in my browser.

So I added a completely nonsensical user-agent header like so:

```
import requests
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json"
payload = {
    "sensor": "false",
     "key": YOUR_KEY_HERE,
     "placeid": SOME_PLACE_ID_HERE,
}
response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers={'user-agent': 'foo'})
content = response.text
```

And the issue vanished. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: If you don't define a user agent in your headers the request library will use: 
"python-requests/2.5.1 CPython/2.7.9 Windows/7" as user agent. My guess is that google triggers on that.

Comment: same issue here ... just put user-agent to None and it work...
Seriously google???  Why do you reject user-agent?? it's an API -_- (and without any info... was working perfectly until this week-end)

Comment: Happened to us as well. Any news as to why?

Comment: Hi jmetz. Can you confirm what user agent request is sending if you don't specify one? If you run this gist it should print the user agent to your console: https://gist.github.com/jmcgill/ba78bf7944117c00fcd6

Comment: Here is what that script printed for me (mac laptop latest os): UserAgent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/14.4.0</p>

Comment: Had the exact same thing happening. Brought down parts of our app, including registration. Nice problem to wake up to on a Saturday morning. Thanks Google!